# NSAttributedString from RTF using iOS Dynamic-Type

Tags: ios, rtf, nsattributedstring

My App has a simple built in help page. The page is loaded from a rich-text file in to an `NSAttributedString`, and the string is displayed in a `UITextView`.

Here's a fragment of code from `prepareForSegue:` where I load the `NSAttributedString` prior to using it for display…

```
NSURL *const textURL =
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"DontPanic"
                        withExtension: @"rtf"];

NSDictionary *const options =
@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType};

NSAttributedString *const text =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithURL: textURL
                                options: options
                     documentAttributes: nil
                                  error: nil];
```

This all works well. However, it doesn't support iOS's ["Dynamic Type"](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type.html) – the fonts are baked in to the RTF file and don't react to the users's settings.

I'd like the guide to use the system defined styles for body: `UIFontTextStyleBody` and heading: `UIFontTextStyleHeadline`.

How might I do this?

I'd be fairly happy for the guide to be defined in another format such as HTML or Markdown. I'd prefer not to add external libraries to the project if I can avoid them, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to preferred fonts through CSS. For example you could create an html document like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 style="font: -apple-system-headine; font-family:-apple-system;">My heading</h1>
        <p style ="font: -apple-system-body; font-family:-apple-system;">The body of this document</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then replace `NSRTFTextDocumentType` with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` in the code you have above.

The full list of preferred font names in CSS is:

```
-apple-system-headline
-apple-system-subheadline
-apple-system-short-headline
-apple-system-short-subheadline
-apple-system-body
-apple-system-short-body
-apple-system-tall-body
-apple-system-caption1
-apple-system-caption2
-apple-system-short-caption1
-apple-system-footnote
-apple-system-short-footnote
```

If you don't want to define the fonts on every element, you can modify the styling in the html `<head>` tag like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      H1 {font: -apple-system-headine; font-family: -apple-system;}
      P {font: -apple-system-body; font-family: -apple-system;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a heading. It will be shown with the dynamic type headline font.</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph. It will use the dynamic type body font.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, that sounds very promising. I'll be quite happy to stop using RTF too – easier to get blank lines in the right place with HTML!

Comment: Is there a way that I can set up those fonts to be used for `<h1>` and `<p>` throughout the document, rather than need to refer to them each time?

Comment: Ah – there is by setting up `<style>` in the `<head>`. I'm going to add an edit to your answer showing how to do this. It might get rejected at moderation –  if you think it's a good edit, would you please accept it? Many thanks.